# Is there a way to make an element always visible using display: fixed;?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm rather new to HTML, I'm working on a website for family, they want a button that sits in the top right corner.

The button works and is in the correct place, the issue is that it only appears if you scroll halfway down the page first and then it will stay.
How can I make it always visible without scrolling down first

It is in Wordpress, so I am stuck using a widget location that exists in the middle of the page or the footer

```
<style>
   #button {
     position: fixed;
     background-image: url(buttonimg.png);
     width: 125px;
     height: 125px;
     background-size: cover;
     border-radius: 100px;
     border: none;
     top: 90px;
     right: 0px;
     z-index: 3
   }

   font {
     line-height: 28px;
     color: black;
   }
</style>

<a href="example.com">
   <button type="button" id="button">
       <font size="4" spacing="0">
          Press this button
       </font>
   </button>
</a>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Note also that `<font>` is an obsolete element and should no longer be used. AND you can't put a `<button>` inside an `<a>`...it's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

change top:90px to top:0. this will place the button at the top of the page.

Comment: there is a sticky header on the page, with top: 0; the header blocks half the button, but even with the top: 90px; the button still does stay at the top of the page where I want it. my issue is it only appears after I scrolled halfway down the page to the location where the widget would normally be. Sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: can you plz send screenshot or link of the site. that will help me to understand better

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand your exact requirement. You can give this style to your button id if you want to put your button at top position:

```
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

It will look something like this:

[image]